# Rails 4 *.json.jbuilder files ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

In my Rails 4.1.1 app (which has the jbuilder gem included), json views always output all columns in the table, ignoring the `app/views/[model]/*.json.jbuilder` files.

In routes.rb, I have:

```
  resources :workshops do
    resources :memberships
    resources :events
  end
```

In events_controller.rb, I have:

```
  # GET /workshop/:workshop_id/events
  # GET /workshop/:workshop_id/events.json
  def index
    @events = @workshop.events    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @events }
    end
  end
```

I set the **@workshop** variable in a "before_action" in the controller.

When I visit `/workshops/f00/events`, it displays in HTML format as expected.

If I make the file, `app/views/events/index.json.jbuilder`:

```
json.events do
end
```

...when I visit `/workshops/f00/events.json`, I expect that the output would be empty. However, I get the contents of the entire @events in JSON format.

What I would like to see is only particular fields being output, given a `app/views/events/index.json.jbuilder` that contains:

```
json.array!(@events) do |event|
  json.extract! event, :id, :title, :description
  json.start event.starts_at
  json.end event.ends_at
  json.url workshop_event_url([@workshop, event], format: :json)
end
```

... but no matter the contents of the .jbuilder file, the output is always the same. Could anyone tell me why my .jbuilder file is being ignored, and how to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

The line `format.json { render json: @events }` will always render the `@events` array since the url `/workshops/f00/events` accepts both `html` and `json` formats and you're rendering `@events` when hitting the url with the `json` format.

If you want to render the data in `app/views/events/index.json.jbuilder` change:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json { render json: @events }
end
```

to:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html 
  format.json
end
```

By not rendering the `@events` array you rely on Rails to output whatever is in `app/views/events/index.json.jbuilder`.